# How to use a system icon for tvOS UIButton?

Tags: xcode, swift, uibutton

Is it possible to use a system icon in a UIButton?

I want to build a `refresh button` like [given here](https://dribbble.com/shots/2604895-Marvel-for-Apple-TV/attachments/519542)

facts: `Swift, Xcode, tvOS`